# How do i eliminate the duplicate count from mysql Group by result?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, max

Please help me to get  the desired result form mysql query.

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM `tbl_jobs` group by `job_user_id`
```

Results :

```
 result given is,              expected result
     cnt                         cnt
      3                           3 
      7                           7
      8                           8
      3                           5
      5
```

Here i dont want the occurence of 3 next time, means no duplicate row 
     of count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tbl_jobs
GROUP BY job_user_id
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Note that a subquery is *not* needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using subquery

```
select distinct cnt from
(
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM tbl_jobs group by job_user_id
)A
```

Comment: This is not an optimal answer because the subquery is unnecessary.